# Does Tailwind CSS tree-shaking work with @apply rules inside *.scss modules?

Tags: webpack, sass, tailwind-css, css-modules, tree-shaking

It's my understanding that Tailwind CSS will tree-shake to only provide bundled CSS with the classes that I'm using. So in the following example:

```html
<div class="flex flex-row">
</div>
```

...the final Tailwind bundle would only include:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

However, I'm wondering if the `@apply` rule works the same? So if I instead had:

```js
import styles from 'styles.scss';

export default function Example() {
  return (
    <div className={ styles.flex_row }>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and...

```scss
.flex_row {
  @apply flex flex-row;
}
```

Would this still tree-shake to give me the minimal bundle of Tailwind classes used?

I've Googled and read through the Tailwind docs, but I haven't been able to turn anything up. I'll see if I can look at the outputted bundle to see if it's evident in there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider defining the rule in a `@layer base/components/utilities` rule and ensuring Tailwind processes the resulting CSS file after Sass has compiled it. This makes the CSS rule "known" to Tailwind, and thus Tailwind will process and "tree-shake" it.

---

As an aside, you may also wish to avoid `@apply` altogether as recommended by Adam Wathan, creator of Tailwind:

- https://twitter.com/adamwathan/status/1226511611592085504

  > Confession: The `apply` feature in Tailwind basically only exists to trick people who are put off by long lists of classes into trying the framework.
  >
  > You should almost never use it
  >
  > Reuse your utility-littered HTML instead.
- https://twitter.com/adamwathan/status/1559250403547652097

  > I can say with absolute certainty that if I started Tailwind CSS over from scratch, there would be no `@​apply`
  >
  > The behavior is outrageously complicated, everyone struggles to build the right mental model of what it's supposed to do, and it encourages bad CSS architecture.

Comment: Thanks @Wongjn, that's very helpful. It doesn't directly answer my question, but it helped me understand some of the intention behind `@apply` and why it is not the way to go.

After inspecting my bundled styles in a local Tailwind project, when I write `@apply` rules under a class it does defeat the purpose of the slim Tailwind model. The bundled CSS includes the custom class (not just the Tailwind classes), so the "tree-shaking" does not seem to work.